# How to track where on page was link clicked?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm taking over development for a site that has three column layout - left (menu, content banners), main (content), right (content banners). They (site owners) use content banners to promote important content.

I'm trying to make them understand that (according to P shape of human reading pattern) items positioned in the bottom right (right column, bottom) are practically invisible to visitors.

How can I track this - where link was clicked - with Google Analytics? I'm thinking about defining regions (left, main, right) and tracking clicks by them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom trackable events: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: How would I use events here? Attach an event on each link?

Comment: No, on the onClick attribute of each link, fire the _gaq.push() event (which is already in GA API so no need for extra work). For each link, you can specify it's category and action. It has worked really well in the past when I've set this up.

Comment: Please remember to use the last GA script block, as an old framework relied on a _gat object instead :)